# Freeform used for two different email addresses

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have always used Freeform for a single form.

For a new project, I need the user to be able to choose two different organisations in a select field. Depending on the option selected the admin email notification needs to be send to one of two email addresses.

I tried using the following code which I made following some of the example documentation on the freeform site, but I am not sure if this is what its meant for.

```
   {exp:freeform:form
   form_id="1"
   required="name|email|message"
   recipients="yes"
   recipient_limit="2"
   recipient_template="admin_notification"
   recipient1="Name 1|email@domain1.com"
   recipient2="Name 2||email@domain2.com""
}
    <p>
        <select name="recipient_email" />
            {freeform:recipients}
                <option value="{freeform:recipient_value}">
                    {freeform:recipient_name}
                </option>
            {/freeform:recipients}
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
    <p>Your Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
    <p>Your Message: <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Can anyone tell me if this is the best route, as it doesn't appear to work as I had hoped. Do I remove the email in the control panel for admin notification? or leave an email there?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your parameters looks correct.

In the **select** part, it should look something like this

```
<select name="recipient_email">
    <option value="{freeform:recipient_value1}">Sales</option>
    <option value="{freeform:recipient_value2}">Technical Support</option>
    <option value="{freeform:recipient_value3}">Service</option>
</select>

OR

<select name="recipient_email">
    <option value="{freeform:recipient_value1}">{freeform:recipient_name1}</option>
    <option value="{freeform:recipient_value2}">{freeform:recipient_name2}</option>
    <option value="{freeform:recipient_value3}">{freeform:recipient_name3}</option>
</select>
```

Hope that helps.
http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#freeform_recipient_name1

Comment: Fix your recipient2 parameter, you have 2 || and double quotes at the end

Comment: Please let me know if this helps